# Can an algebraic function be multivalued?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can an algebraic function be multivalued? Can a multivalued function be an algebraic function?

A multivalued function is a function $F$ with $F\colon z\mapsto (F_1(z),F_2(z),...,F_n(z))$ with $n>1$ where $F_1$, $F_2$, ..., $F_n$ are functions.

By definition of the algebraic functions, an algebraic function must be the root of an irreducible algebraic equation. But can an $n$-tuple with $n>1$ be the root of an algebraic equation?

What if the different branches (Branches of what?) are the components of the function value of the multivalued function? Is such a function algebraic?

Comment: I think you are asking a question about 2 different concepts: multi-valued function (see for example http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultivaluedFunction.html) and a function from a set $X$ to a set $X^n$.

Comment: I see now I have to say "set-valued function".

Comment: An algebraic function has to be a function. But a function cannot be multivalued. "Multivalued function" is a misnomer because a function can be only one-to-one or many-to-one. For treating multivalued functions as functions, you have to treat them as set-valued functions or as tuple-valued functions. Look therefore for the comments and answers at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246561/can-an-algebraic-function-be-set-valued