# Can an algebraic function be set-valued?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can an algebraic function be set-valued? Can a set-valued function be an algebraic function?

A set-valued function is a function $F$ with $F\colon z\mapsto \{F_1(z),F_2(z),...,F_n(z)\}$ with $n>1$ where $F_1$, $F_2$, ..., $F_n$ are functions.

By definition of the algebraic functions, an algebraic function must be the root of an irreducible algebraic equation. But can a set be the root of an algebraic equation?

What if the different branches are the components of the function value of the set-valued function? Is such a function algebraic?

Comment: Where does live $z$ and $F(z)$ ?

Comment: Let us assume for simplicity $z$ and $F_{i}(z)$ are real or are complex

Comment: An algebraic function $f$ with $y=f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ is by definition a root of a polynomial equation (the defining algebraic equation of $f$) $p_0(x_1,...,x_n)+p_1(x_1,...,x_n)y+p_2(x_1,...,x_n)y^2+...$$+p_n(x_1,...,x_n)y^n=0$ where the $p_i$ ($\forall i=0,1,2,...,n$) are polynomials in $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$. If you want to allow $f$ to be set-valued, you have to allow powers of sets for $y^2,y^3,...,y^n$ in the defining algebraic equation of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an algebraic function can be set-valued, and a set-valued function can be an algebraic function. A function is algebraic iff each of its branches is an algebraic function.